# get Qty Increments

Tags: php, quantity, magento2.1.6, qty-increment

Do you know how I can get the "Qty Increments" on the product page?

Product page back end:
[image]

Code 'addtocart.phtml':
[image]

With this code, I have a blank field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try following way:

```
<?php
$qtyIncrements = 0;
$validators =  $block->getQuantityValidators();
if(isset($validators['validate-item-quantity']) && isset($validators['validate-item-quantity']['qtyIncrements'])) {
    $qtyIncrements = $validators['validate-item-quantity']['qtyIncrements'];
}
?>
<input type="number" name="inc_qty" value="<?php echo $qtyIncrements;?>"/>
```

[Check here how to add stock data into product view block](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Block/Plugin/ProductView.php#L45)